# primes of the strict henselization

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to get some intuition for the (strict) henselization of a local ring.

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$. I'm happy to assume it is Noetherian and normal. Let $p\subset m$ be a prime ideal.

From basic facts of the strict henselization, I know that $mA^{h}$ is the unique prime ideal of $A^{h}$ lying above $m$.

1. Is $pA^{h}$ necessarily prime? What about $pA^{sh}$?
2. I'm guessing the answer is no, in which case, how should one think about the primes of $A^h$ or $A^{sh}$ lying over $p$? (For example, if $A$ is the local ring of a point $x$ in a scheme, then the primes of $A$ are "germs" of closed subschemes passing through $x$). Do they have the same height?
3. Why is $mA^h, mA^{sh}$ still maximal if $pA^h,pA^{sh}$ isn't?
4. Is it possible to recover $(A_p)^h$ or $(A_p)^{sh}$ from $A^h$ or $A^{sh}$ by localizing $A^h$ or $A^{sh}$ at some prime lying above $p$ and then (strict) henselizing again?

What's a good reference for this?

Comment: Not a complete answer, just an example I use to have an intuition. Consider the curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$. It has a node at the origin. However the two branches of the node can't be distinguished in the local ring, and indeed, the local ring is integral. However, the henselization is not integral anymore, and is isomorphic to the henselization of the local ring of $y^2=x^2$. It then has two minimal primes corresponding to the branches of the node. So you can think of the primes ideal of $A^h$ as the analytical branches passing through the given point, and the maximal ideal of $A^h$ is still maximal.

Comment: Dear @Roland, could you recommend a reference for (strict) Henselizations? Namely a book which includes calculations and examples?

Comment: @Arrow The chapters in the stacks project are also quite good.

Comment: Dear @Roland, in your first comment, when you write "the local ring is integral", you merely mean it's an integral domain, right?

Comment: @Arrow, yes sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Dear @Roland, did you mean the strict henselizations of the *real* points are isomorphic, or did you refer to the complex points?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Strict henselization is not about $k$-valued points.

Comment: I'm thinking of strict henselization as a universal cover, so it seems strange to me that the cusp and the node (over the reals) have the same strict henselization.